# What are the benefits/differences when annotating a Java REST resource with @Stateless?

Tags: java, rest

For example, consider the following REST resource running on a WildFly (or another JavaEE app server) instance...

```
@Path("/library")
public class Library {

   @GET
   @Path("/books")
   public String getBooks() {...}
}
```

and

```
@Stateless
@Path("/library")
public class Library {

   @GET
   @Path("/books")
   public String getBooks() {...}
}
```

What are the differences in how the application server handles these classes when the resource is called by a client program? What are the benefits of annotating a REST resource as stateless?

Comment: By annotating with `@Stateless` you are making it a (stateless) `EJB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jersey implementation of Jax-rs 2.0 if no annotation is present, the default is @RequestScope.

> Default lifecycle (applied when no annotation is present). In this scope the resource instance is created for each new request and used for processing of this request. If the resource is used more than one time in the request processing, always the same instance will be used. This can happen when a resource is a sub resource is returned more times during the matching. In this situation only on instance will server the requests.

If you use @Stateless annotation, your class becomes a Stateless EJB. This allows to have a container managed instance pool. Allowing to reuse instances, usually improving scalability.